# Displaying a div on top of another without using z-index

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, z-index, overlap

I've created custom drop down menus that have one `<div>` holding the current value and acting as a `<select>` field and another below it that gets displayed when the top one is clicked, holding all the `<option>` values.

The design requires the bottom `<div>` to position slightly below the upper one (weird rounded corners, etc) so I used `z-index` to achieve that. It all works until the moment I have two drop down menus close to each other. If you click the upper one the drop down option list is displayed but it goes below the second drop down menu as well which is highly undesirable. Here's simplified version in a jsfiddle:
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nc4L5dd6/1/)

As you can see, the first drop down menu is fine but the second one is hidden below the third one. Any ideas how can I achieve this so the second menu works as well? May be without using z-index somehow?

Comment: Can more than one dropdown be open at a time? In your example, two are open, however, will it be that way in practice?

Comment: Two cannot be opened at the same time. If you check the jsFiddle you will see that the third one is not opened but the second one is still hidden below it. I've displayed the first one as opened just to show that it is far away from the other ones but in practice this will not happen. The problem with the other two stands still though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, wrap each menu in an element. I used a `div.container`.

Since only one menu is going to be open at a time, simply changing the `z-index` of the `.major` and `.minor` elements in each container (on hover in my example) works correctly:

```css
.major {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 1;
}
.minor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  z-index: 0;
  display: none;
}
.container:hover .major {
  z-index: 5;
}
.container:hover .minor {
  display: block;
  z-index: 4;
}
.moveup {
  margin-top: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="major">
    First one fine
  </div>
  <div class="minor">
    Option part goes here Option part goes here Option part goes here
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div class="container">
  <div class="major">
    Second menu
  </div>
  <div class="minor">
    Option part goes here Option part goes here Option part goes here
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="major">
    Third menu
  </div>
  <div class="minor">
    Option part goes here Option part goes here Option part goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but if I'm not wrong, the solution should be to wrap the .major and .minor divs so they don't overlap each other, like so:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="major">
  First one fine
  </div>
  <div class="minor">
  Option part goes here
  Option part goes here
  Option part goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

See my fork of your JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jk1dn4yx/

Comment: Won't work: https://jsfiddle.net/jk1dn4yx/1/
The two .major parts can be one below the other, I cannot control that and it is actually fine when the dropdown menus are not displayed. However, as soon as you click on the upper one (which is not available in the demo, I display it straight as opened there) the blue part is made visible and it is behind the lower red div which is actually the problem...

Comment: But you can add a wrapping div?
If you also add a class when opening the .minor div, for example "open", try this extended z-index solution: https://jsfiddle.net/jk1dn4yx/2/
Also try Hatchet's solution, which seems to be basically what I did for this comment, before I saw Hatchet's answer. :)

Comment: Yep, he is also changing the z-index though, that should work.